# Is Looping inside a Task Recommended?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, loops, task

Is Looping inside a task really recommended?

example code:

```
public void doTask(){
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        do{
           // do tasks here.... call webservice
        }while(true till cancelled)
    });
}
```

any answers would be great! :) 
because it is a case for my webservice calling right now, and the memory consumption goes out of control.

So may I ask, is looping inside a task really good or not recommended at all?

As Requested by SLC, heres the code:

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSrc;
Task myTask;
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isPressed = !isPressed;



    if(isPressed)
    {
        tokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();
        myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            do{
                checkMatches(tokenSrc.Token);
            }while(tokenSrc.IsCancellationRequested != true);
        }, tokenSrc.Token);
    }
    else {
        try{
            tokenSrc.Cancel();
            // Log to notepad
        }
        catch(Exception err){
           // Log to notepad
        }
        finally {
           if(myTask.IsCanceled || myTask.IsCompleted || myTask.isFaulted) {
               myTask.Dispose();
           }
        }

    }
}

private void checkMatches(CancellationTokenSource token) 
{
    try
    {
        if(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
           //Create Endpoint...
           //Bypass ServCertValidation for test purposes
           ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate {return true;});
           using(WebServiceAsmx.SoapClient client = new....)
           {
               client.CheckResp response = client.chkMatch();
               // if's here for the response then put to logs
           }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        // err.toLogs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to do this, especially if your task runs constantly, for example picking up a message queue.

```
while (not shutting down)
   get next email to send
   if exists next email to send
      send
   else
      wait for 10 seconds
wend
```

Ensure that you have a way to get out if you need to cancel it, like you've done with a flag, and you should be fine.

Regarding webservices:

You should have no problem calling the webservice repeatedly, nor should it cause any memory spikes. However, you should make sure your initialisation code is not inside the loop:

BAD

```
while (notShuttingDown)
   make a new connection
   initialise
   make a call to the service()
wend
```

GOOD

```
make a new connection
initialise
while (notShuttingDown)
    make a call to the service
wend
```

Depending on your webservice it might be more optimal to create a batch operation, for example if your service is HTTP then hitting it repeatedly involves a lot of overhead. A persistent TCP connection might be better because it could be creating and destroying a lot of objects to make the calls.

For example

slow, lots of overhead:

```
myRecords = { cat, dog, mouse }

foreach record in myRecords
    webservice check record
endforeach
```

faster:

```
myRecords = { cat, dog, mouse }
webservice check [myRecords] // array of records is passed instead of one by one
```

Debugging: The most likely risk is that somehow the task is not being disposed correctly - can you add this to your method to debug?

```
myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            Console.Writeline("Task Started");
            do{
                checkMatches(tokenSrc.Token);
                Thread.Sleep(10); // Some pause to stop your code from going as fast as it possibly can and putting your CPU usage to 100% (or 100/number of cores%)
            }while(tokenSrc.IsCancellationRequested != true);
            Console.Writeline("Task Stopped");
        }
```

You might have to change that so it writes to a file or similar depending on if you have a console.

Then run it and make sure that only 1 task is being created.

Comment: does it also apply to webservices? like after receiving response it will again loop back to call the webservices?

Comment: in you bad example for calling webservices. does initialization of it inside a loop causes memory spikes? because ive been experiencing it, and it's giving me a lot of headaches.

Comment: It is very possible yes, if you are creating objects repeatedly. If you edit your question and post your actual code it will be easier to spot where it might be spiking

Comment: Cool, well it looks OK, but as a check, can you add some debugging into your task? I have added the debugging to my answer to try. Also you should put a `Thread.Sleep(10);` into your loop otherwise it will drive your CPU usage up to 100%

Comment: I suspect then that the memory consumption is not in your code, but instead is inside the webservice. I can't see anything wrong in your code above.

Comment: Does webservice connection consume memory in a localpc after it has been called?